# otpInputs not changing focusedBorderColor to other color

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

```
<OtpInputs
    key={this.state.completions}
    inputContainerStyles={styles2.otpInputStyle}
    keyboardType='numeric'
    numberOfInputs={6}
    focusedBorderColor='#FFBB00'         
/>
```

in the code i want to change the color of my otpInput box when the focus is on that box it changing the color but only to the blue and that is default one

Comment: ```react-native-otp-inputs``` used ```textContentType='oneTimeCode'``` default color in ReactNative TextInput as the box color. So currently there is no possible way to change that color from above library.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

For changing focus of border colour, you may use below code

```
<OtpInputs
   focusStyles={styles.focusStyle}
/>
```

**focusStyles** will help you to change focusedBorderColor

Happy Coding!